# How to add the proper javascript to a page for using the Chartbeat module?

Tags: javascript

Has anyone successfully used the [Chartbeat](https://www.drupal.org/project/chartbeat) module with Drupal to get the analytics statistics?

It doesn't seem to work for me. I don't get the proper javascript added to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the module doesn't work for me, I ended up putting the required javascript code into the template files.